# Dedication page in undergraduate thesis

Tags: thesis, undergraduate, dedication

Is it considered embarassing if adding a dedication to the family on the second page and giving credit in the acknowledgement section in the end for the support during hardships in an undergraduate thesis? What's too much and of disadvantage? Or is an undergraduate thesis quite forgiving and the question of 'too much' isn't an issue here?

Comment: Why would it ever be a problem?

Comment: The worst I can see happening is that, given dedications are more commonly seen in more major theses (such as PhD), it might be interpreted as slightly self-important. But more likely, it would not have any impact.

Comment: It is not abnormal. Several students of my graduation epoch (80s) did so - from both extremes of the class! It's not about showing your orthodoxy to the 4th commandment or acknowledging the contribution of classmates or staff. It's just giving credit where credit is due. If you feel no desire to do so, whatever others may be doing, then do not do it.